# Android: Open a custom pop up dialog from an options menu

Tags: android, dialog, popup, android-optionsmenu

Is it possible to have an option menu item that opens a dialog window?
Here's what I've got:

```
public class main extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int score;
    
    SharedPreferences stats = getSharedPreferences("TRHprefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    score = stats.getInt("score", 0);
    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        
        case R.id.score:
                            
            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.options_menu);
            dialog.setTitle("Hero Stats");
            
            TextView b10 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tolevel);
            b10.setText("Score: " + score);

            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();

                            break;
        case R.id.options:     
            //Options

                            break;
        case R.id.quit: 
            //Quit
                            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

When I select the score options button, the app force closes. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the logcat output, it is just guessing without it.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the logcat output to make it easier to determine what exactly is going wrong, but staring at the code my expectation is that either:

1. There is an error in the layout file `options_menu.xml` and the line `TextView b10 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tolevel);` is returning a null value for `b10`. If that happens the next line will cause a NullPointerException and the app will force close.
2. `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);` is failing because you're passing in an ApplicationContext rather than an Activity. Try using `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);`.